# .NET analog for COM OutProc Server

Tags: .net, com

I need move some piece of .NET code into another process. (Because it should use x86 and x64 native libraries).

I know that COM OutProc server can be used in this situation, but may be for .NET exists more native technology which do not require system wide registrations in registry/GAC?

UPDATE:

One of features I expect to be supported - start server (executable file?) and shutdown it on demand from client application.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf

Comment: Is WCF able activate (start) exe file with server implementation on demand? I was sure that it cannot and do not consider it. May be I am wrong?

Comment: @SergeyAzarkevich: Is it required that WCF is able to start the external process? You can control that from the main process yourself, using `Process.Start`, can't you?

Comment: @Dirk Vollmar yes, I can. But if exists some framework that do most of job I better use it. If no, then of course Process.Start + WCF can be used.